# In columns of inviter and invitee how to find inviters with 1, 2, 3 prior invites?

Tags: python, mysql

NOTE: I am alright with using MySQL or python

EDIT: To make my question MRE as suggested by user: strawberry, I create my table like (created, deleted table isn't really necessary so I just used all same date):

```
CREATE table invites (
  ID                INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  invitee_id        INT,
  inviter_id        INT,
  inviter_user_code VARCHAR(20),
  created_at        datetime,
  updated_at        datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
); 
INSERT INTO invites (invitee_id, inviter_id, inviter_user_code, created_at,updated_at)
VALUES 
  (17365, 17374, 'BDMX5Z', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01'),
  (17401, 17349, 'BDMX58', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01'),
  (17403, 17349, 'BDMX58', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01'),
  (17452, 17349, 'BDMX8C', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01'),
  (17457, 17449, 'BDMX8J', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01');
```

To make myself clear here is what my dataframe looks like:

```
    id invitee_id   inviter_id  inviter_user_code   created_at           updated_at
    1   17375       17374             BDMX5Z    2019-02-01 10:28:44 2019-02-01 10:28:44
    2   17401       17349             BDMX58    2019-02-01 11:59:47 2019-02-01 11:59:47
    3   17403       17349             BDMX58    2019-02-01 12:03:22 2019-02-01 12:03:22
    4   17452       17449             BDMX8C    2019-02-01 13:39:31 2019-02-01 13:39:31
    5   17457       17455             BDMX8J    2019-02-01 14:00:25 2019-02-01 14:00:25
    6   17502       17501             BDMX9Y    2019-02-01 15:50:44 2019-02-01 15:50:44
    7   17541       17540             BDMXB7    2019-02-01 17:15:06 2019-02-01 17:15:06
    8   17542       17546             BDMXBD    2019-02-01 17:34:48 2019-02-01 17:34:48
    9   17696       17630             BDMXDZ    2019-02-02 11:46:14 2019-02-02 11:46:14
    10  17706       13191             BDMT3A    2019-02-02 12:23:47 2019-02-02 12:23:47
```

`invitee_id` are users' that have been invited. 
`inviter_id` are users' who've invited new users.

So if you are first to invite with no prior invite `inviter_id` will not be included in `invitee_id`.

for this I'done

```
select 
  *
from user_invitations
where
  inviter_id in
    (select invitee_id
     from user_invitations)
```

After this I will have `inviter_id` as inviters with prior invitation.

My question is how to get inviters with prior invitation (by whom also had prior invitation) and so on...
I've tried multiple methods in mysql directly and by creating df and working with it.

doing the above query on the resulting table like:

```
With one_prior as (
    select 
      *
    from user_invitations
    where
      inviter_id in
        (select invitee_id
          from user_invitations)
) 
select *
from one_prior
where 
  inviter_id in
   (select invitee_id 
    from one_prior);
```

I've manually check for one user and it seems right however if there a way to check all of them?

I've created two queries:

```
select *
from user_invitations
where inviter_id = 17349;


select *
from user_invitations
where invitee_id = 23764;
```

and check back and forth.
for example if inviter_id=17349 is first to invite with no prior invite it would not appear in 2nd query. Then from result of first query with inviter_id=17349 I get invitee_id = 17401, 17403, etc.. which then I will put them into first query as inviter_id now. Repeat the steps.

Furthermore is there a way to create a distributed points plot where each point represents users and there is a line connecting linking users that have "inviter/invitee" relationships?

Edit:
say for fifth link I am doing and code seems long and tedious I am hoping to find more efficient method.

```
query = """
With five_prior as
(
    With four_prior as
    (
        With three_prior as 
        (
            With two_prior as 
            (
                With one_prior as 
                (
                    select 
                      *
                    from user_invitations
                    where inviter_id in
                          (select invitee_id
                          from user_invitations)
                ) 
            select *
            from one_prior
            where inviter_id in
                  (select invitee_id 
                   from one_prior)
            ) 
        select *
        from two_prior
        where inviter_id in
              (select invitee_id 
               from two_prior)
        )
    select *
    from three_prior
    where inviter_id in
          (select invitee_id
           from three_prior)
    )
select *
from four_prior
where inviter_id in
      (select invitee_id
       from four_prior)
)

select *
from five_prior
where inviter_id in
      (select invitee_id
       from five_prior)
group by inviter_id
"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)

five_link = list(df.inviter_id)
print(len(five_link))
```

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL query answer or something in Python?

Comment: Either one is fine.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way you could do it in python, using a dynamic programming solution:

```
previous_invites = { r["invitee"]: 0 for r in rows }

changed = True

while changed:
  changed = False
  for r in rows:
    update_prev_invites = max(previous_invites[r["invitee"]], previous_invites.get(r["inviter"], 0) + 1)
    if update_prev_invites > previous_invites[r["invitee"]]:
      changed = True
      previous_invites[r["invitee"]] = update_prev_invites

for r in rows:
  print "User " + str(r["id"]) + " had a chain of " + str(previous_invites[r["invitee"]]) + " inviter(s) behind them"
```

This assumes `rows` is an array of dictionaries containing the data in the database. It builds the `previous_invites` dictionary (which maps invitees to number of inviters in their 'chain') by setting an invitees `previous_invites` value to the `previous_invites` of its inviter + 1. This loop is run until the dictionary converges on the correct answers.

With `n` users and `m` being the length of the longest chain of inviters, this solution runs in O(n) space and O(n*m) time.

Comment: Thanks! I don't undesrtand rows. what key-value pair is it going to have on each dictionary in an array? [{inviter_id:[invitees]}]?

Comment: I'm imagining that data is coming straight out of the database, so it would look something like: `[{id:1, invitee:17375, inviter:17374, inviter_user_code:"BDMX5Z",...}, ... ]` Sorry, I think I might have used slightly different names than your schema showed, but it's an array of dictionaries, where the keys in the dictionary are column names, and the values are values from database rows.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! seems much more efficient then creating multiple CTE.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use Networkx library,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'inviter_id', 'invitee_id', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
nx.draw_networkx(G)

[(i,list(G.successors(i))) for i in G.nodes() if len(list(G.predecessors(i))) == 0]

[f'Inviter {str(i)} invites {", ".join(map(str, list(G.successors(i))))}' for i in G.nodes() if len(list(G.predecessors(i))) == 0]
```

Output:

```
['Inviter 17374 invites 17375',
 'Inviter 17349 invites 17401, 17403',
 'Inviter 17449 invites 17452',
 'Inviter 17455 invites 17457',
 'Inviter 17501 invites 17502',
 'Inviter 17540 invites 17541',
 'Inviter 17546 invites 17542',
 'Inviter 17630 invites 17696',
 'Inviter 13191 invites 17706']
```

Graph Network Image:

[image]